# MySQL index of column which needs count by prefix

Tags: mysql, index, count

My table (InnoDB) has a column `name varchar(255) NOT NULL`, which consists of such data:

```
A:something
B:another
... ...
```

I want to make the following query fast, when the data grows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE valid=1 UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE valid=1 AND name LIKE 'A:%' UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE valid=1 AND name LIKE 'B:%'
```

How should I index the `name` column?  Note: I **only** want to **count** total valid values, and values starting with "A:" or "B:" respectively.

The MySQL versions are v5.7 and v8.0.

Comment: Inconsistency:  "spec" vs "name".

Comment: changed spec to name to be consistent to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INDEX(valid, name)
```

in that order.  That will be "covering" as well as "composite".

Discussion:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Also, change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` to avoid the unnecessary (and probably unwanted) `DISTINCT`.

This is likely to be faster (still using the `INDEX` above):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total',
       SUM(name LIKE 'A:%') AS 'As',
       SUM(name LIKE 'B:%') AS 'Bs'
    FROM table
    WHERE valid = 1;
```

If there will be a lot of rows that are not 'valid', consider removing them from the table.  (It is unclear how much this would speed things up.)

That index will be optimal.  But it will still get slower as the table numbers increase.